# Sometimes bus service may/might be cancelled on the route

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense, present-simple

1. Sometimes bus service **may/might** be cancelled on the route.

Without any more context, does it refer to the present?

a) *It is possible that sometimes bus service **is** cancelled on the route*. (maybe sometimes it is true, maybe sometimes not)

Or, does it refer to the future?

b) It is possible that sometimes bus service **will be** cancelled on the route. (maybe sometimes it will be true **in the future**, maybe sometimes not)

Note: I'm not sure if "cancelled" is an adjective or a verb here. I assumed it as an adjective.

Comment: The sentence looks badly written. I'd assume a non-native author (missing articles, or incorrect pluralisation).  What is the source?

Comment: Do you mean both "**the** bus service" or "bus service**s**" would be correct here?

Comment: Also should it be "**for** the route" -- *The bus service for the route...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a clear time reference here, and one would assume that it could apply to  both the current state of the bus service, or the state at a future (or even past) time.

Comment: How would it refer to a state in the past?

Comment: I would infer that as the bus service might be cancelled in the future, it might have been cancelled in the past, unless there was so reason to think otherwise.

Comment: Would you also answer the two questions in the comments above, please?

Comment: New questions should really be put in questions not comments.  But yes "a/the service" or  "services", and perhaps "on this route" or omitting that part. Now can you clarify by adding the source of the quote to your question?

Comment: Actually the source is me. I thought "service" was an uncountable noun. But after your comment, I looked it up in an online dictionary and found that it's a countable noun. The reason behind asking the question is that I wanted to know whether "may/might" work with "sometimes", especially when the sentence refers to the present time.